# I need to construct a family tree based on the specifications given below. want it to be in Java

Tags: java, tree

The input will be as

Name of parent number of children names of children separated by space 
END
Number of lines in next input 
Ancestor child

Eg:

> heena 2 kishan kinjal
>
> Kishan 1 ansh
>
> END
>
> 1
>
> Kinjal ansh

Here as shown in example we can take multiple line Input and input is terminated by END. After that we give a number which specifies how many lines are there in next input.
The next input asks whether kinjal is ancestor of ansh or not.
The output should be NO.

Can anyone help?

I have created 2 separate list containing number and names. I am totally lost please help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class test3
{

    //static int index;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> temp=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> number=new ArrayList<>();
        String t="";
        String t1="END";
        String rootfromlist="";

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            t=scan.next();
            if(t.equals(t1)) {
                break;
            } else {
                temp.add(t);
            }
        }

        String[] temp2=new String[temp.size()];

        for(int i=0;i<temp2.length;i++)
        {
            temp2[i]=temp.get(i);
        }

        Iterator<String> itr=temp.iterator();

        String regex="[0-9]+";
        int i=0,j=0;

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            temp2[i]=(String)itr.next();
            if(temp2[i].matches(regex))
            {
                number.add(Integer.parseInt(temp2[i]));
                i--;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                words.add(temp2[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }

        Iterator itr2=number.iterator();

        while(itr2.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr2.next());
        }

        System.out.println(number.get(0));

        List<String> wodupli=words.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<>();
        boolean prev=false;
        int index=0;
        String tt="null";

        //here i am trying to make list "a" such that as array of binary tree. that is then i will able to access children of node by formula 2*i+1 and 2*i+2. but the logic id not correct

        for(int k=0;k<number.size();k++)
        {
            if(number.get(k)==2)
            {
                if(prev==false)
                {
                    a.add(wodupli.get(index));
                    a.add(wodupli.get(2*index+1));
                    a.add(wodupli.get(2*index+2));
                }
                if(prev==true)
                {

                    a.add(wodupli.get(index-1));
                    a.add(wodupli.get(2*index));
                    a.add(wodupli.get(2*index+1));

                }
                index=index+3;
                prev=false;
            }
            if(number.get(k)==1)
            {
                a.add(wodupli.get(index));
                a.add(wodupli.get(index+1));
                a.add(tt);

                index+=3;
                prev=true;
            }
        }

        for(int l=0;l<a.size();l++)
        {
            System.out.println(a.get(l));
        }
    }
}
```

i want to know how to create a tree dynamically. because here binary tree logic wont work.

Comment: Show what you have tried and elaborate on what is wrong with your solution. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Try yourself `first` , if you get any `error` then post here , we will help you to solve that

Comment: try coding yourself. I think the most difficult part here is splitting the input up correctly. storing it in a suited type (TreeMap or something else) should be easy. So start coding and show us what you did and what is not working in your code

Comment: Not knowing where to begin can be paralysing, I know, been there, done that.  One important thing is to just do something, it won't always be the right thing, but it might lead you to better answers.  Things that come to mind; `Scanner`, since the format is relatively simple and well known (`String`, `int`, series of `n` optional `String`s).  Another, more brute force method, would be to use `String#split` to break it down into seperate values which can more easily be parsed

Comment: Also, don't try and solve the "whole" problem, break it down and solve each part, start by figuring out how you might parse the first line of the text

Comment: 6 down votes within few minutes must feel like swimming in a pool of sharks. Don't get discouraged by it. We are code-hungry predators.  First try to get all the input and print it out. Next you want to store this information. This is where objects come in mind. If the input describes a person, you may start with a `Person` class which has some attributes like name (`String`) and children (`ArrayList` of `String`, or better `ArrayList` of `Person`).

Comment: @c0der exactly.. i am a newbee here and also at programming.. i have added what i have done so far.

Comment: OK.  So, now what is your question?  "Please help me" or "can you help me?" is not a question.  It is an appeal for help.  But you want our help you need you to explain clearly and specifically what is giving you problems.  And if you cannot articulate what your problems are, I recommend that you talk to your teacher or tutor.

Comment: You will understand what we are getting at if your read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: As suggested  in my previous comment consider a `Person` class. Use the input information to construct a `Person` object for each person entered.

Comment: @StephenC yes i understood, i have edited the question.

Comment: See code [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/krgGTI8Bba).  You need a method that constructs and returns `Person` instead of `printPerson`

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your problem seems to be that you don't know what data structure to use.

As you have figured out, an binary search tree is not what you need:

1. A binary search tree is for looking up things using a key.  The tree represents the relationships between keys and values.  You want to represent the relationships between values; i.e. people in a family tree.
2. A family tree is not binary.  One person can have more than two children.

So what you actually need to do is to design a class that represents a person: lets call it `Person`.  A `Person` will need to represent at least the following things about the person:

- the person's name
- the person's children ... which could be a list or an array

Secondly, you will need some kind of map data structure that maps a person's name to their `Person` object.  You can use a `Map<String, Person>` for this.

Next you need some code that will read your input file, and create the `Person` records and populate the map.   The code should also be linking up the Person records into the family tree(s).

Finally, you will need some simple code that will answer the question "is A an ancestor of B".  Hint: that is the same question as "is B a descendant of A" ... which can be answered by recursively walking the tree for "A".

The bad news is that most of the code you have written probably needs to be thrown away.  The good news is that the new code will be a lot more logical / easier to understand.

Comment: Okay... I don't mind throwing my code.. well thanks for the help.. I will try with the logic u suggested

Comment: "you will need some kind of map data structure that maps a person's name to their Person object. You can use a Map<String, Person> for this."  since the person name is already included in `Person` I would prefer a simple collection of all `Person` objects, say `List<Person>` as I proposed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801555/i-need-to-construct-a-family-tree-based-on-the-specifications-given-below-want#comment100158300_56801555)

Comment: @c0der thanks you for helping!